# Uniqueness in Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a slight problem with the proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem, particularly the uniqueness part.

Suppose we have a Hilbert space $H$ and a non-zero linear functional $f : H\rightarrow\mathbb F$. The proof I have seen begins as follows. Since $f$ is non-zero, there exists a $z\in(\ker f)^\perp$ such that $f(z) = 1$ and $\|z\| = 1$. It then proceeds to show that $f(x) = \langle x, z\rangle$ for all $x\in H$. This part is fine.

The uniqueness is confusing me though, because to me this seems to suggest that there is precisely one vector $z\in (\ker f)^\perp$ such that $f(z) = 1$ and $\|z\| = 1$. This seems unlikely to me. Is this true? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your question as to why this would be expected, maybe this will help.
$$ f : H \to \mathbb{F}$$
If $H$ is finite dimensional (dim = $n$), then by the Rank-Nullity theorem,
$$ \text{Null}(f) + \text{Rank}(f)=n$$
but $\mathbb{F}$ has dimension 1 so $\text{Rank}(f) \le 1$. Thus, ''most'' elements of $H$ are in the null space of $f$. In the infinite-dimensional case, all elements except those in the span of $z$ are actually in the null space of $f$.

Comment: Oh of course. Yeah that clears it up. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If there were a second one ($\bar z$, say), you have
$$\langle z,x\rangle = \langle \bar z,x\rangle\quad \forall x$$
which implies
$$\langle z-\bar z ,x\rangle = 0 \quad \forall x $$
so in particular

$$\langle z-\bar z , z-\bar z\rangle =||z - \bar z ||^2= 0 \quad
\Rightarrow z=\bar z $$

Comment: But doesn't it seem strange that there is only one vector with that value under $f$? That seems quite strange to me. I'm not saying it's not true, I understand the proof, but I guess I'm looking for some intuition as to why there's only one $z$ with $f(z) = 1$ and $\|z\| = 1$.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity (oh and thank you!)