# Riesz Representation Theorem and Uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through the proof of the Reisz Representation Theorem in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* and am confused about the uniqueness portion of the proof.

Axler claims:

> "Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\phi $ is a linear functional on V. Then there is a unique vector $u \in V$ such $$ \phi(v) = \langle v,u \rangle$$ for every $v \in V$."

The text then proceeds to prove existence (which I understand, so am not going to elaborate here) and then uniqueness of $ u$.

To prove uniqueness, the text claims the following:

> Now we prove that only one vector $ u \in V $ has the desired behavior.
>
> Suppose $ u_1, u_2 \in V $ are such that $$ \phi(v) = \langle v,u_1 \rangle = \langle v,u_2 \rangle $$ for every $v \in V$. Then $$ 0 = \langle v,u_1 \rangle - \langle v,u_2 \rangle = \langle v,u_1-u_2 \rangle $$ for every $ v \in V$. Taking $ v = u_1 - u_2 $ shows that $ u_1 - u_2 = 0 $. In other words, $u_1 = u_2$, completing the proof.

Some questions about this:

By "taking $ v = u_1 - u_2 $", I assume the text means that we set $ v = u_1 - u_2 $. However, why does $ 0 = \langle u_1 - u_2 , u_1 - u_2 \rangle \implies u_1 - u_2 = 0 $?

Isn't $\langle u_1 - u_2 , u_1 - u_2 \rangle = (u_1 - u_2)^T (u_1 - u_2) $? As a result, isn't $\langle u_1 - u_2 , u_1 - u_2 \rangle = 0 $ iff $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R^n}$? (The text assumes that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R^n}$ or $\mathbb{C^n}$.)

(I realize that this might be more of a question about whether $AA^T = 0 \implies A = 0$, and I've already looked at a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044527/prove-that-aat-0-implies-a-0) about that. However, I've included details of the proof, just in case my interpretation of what it was saying was wrong. I've also looked at [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317043/uniqueness-in-riesz-representation-theorem) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738045/riesz-representation-theorem-in-linear-algebra) that also discuss this line of the proof, but am still confused about the calculation above.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(v)=\langle v,u_1\rangle=\langle v,u_2\rangle$, then $\langle v,u_1-u_2\rangle=0$ for any choice of $v\in V$. So, cleverly choose $v=u_1-u_2$. Then 
$$ 0=\langle u_1-u_2,u_1-u_2\rangle.$$
One of the conditions in the definition of an inner product is that $\langle w,w\rangle=0$ if and only $w=0$. So, $u_1-u_2=0$ and $u_1=u_2$. As a concrete example, let's examine the standard inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=x\cdot y$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $x_i$ denote the components of $x$ and $y_i$ those of $y$, then 
$$ x\cdot y=\sum_{i=1}^3 x_iy_i=x^Ty.$$
Note that 
$$ \langle x,x\rangle=x\cdot x=\sum_{i=1}^3x_i^2\ge 0$$
and equals zero exactly when $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.

Comment: Thank you -- that's very helpful. I completely forgot about this property. As a followup, suppose we have a vector v = [1+i; -1+i]; in this case, <v,v> = adj(v)*v = 0, which violates definiteness. Does this mean that v is not in an inner product space?

Comment: Once you work over the complex field, the appropriate generalization of the standard dot product is $\langle z,w\rangle =\overline{z}^T\cdot w$.

Comment: Right, so $ \langle v,v \rangle = adj(v)*v = \overline{v}^T v = [1-i, -1-i] * \begin{bmatrix}1+i; \\ -1+i \end{bmatrix} = 0 $. But doesn't this violate definiteness since $ v \neq 0 $?

Comment: Check your calculations: $\overline{v}^Tv=4$ here.

Comment: My bad -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ induces on a vector space the norm $$ \|v\|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}. $$ One of the properties of the norm is that $$ \|v\|=0\Leftrightarrow v=0. $$ Then, specialising this property to the proof of the theorem, we have $$ \langle u_1-u_2, u_1-u_2\rangle=0\Leftrightarrow \|u_1-u_2\|=0 \Leftrightarrow    u_1=u_2. $$ This is a trick used very often in Hilbert spaces.